# Slow compilation with modified linux kernel

Tags: c, compilation, linux-kernel, virtualbox, kernel-module

I am currently using CENTOS 6.1 in latest virtualbox for building my code base which is in C.

It takes hardly 15min to complete the compilation.

I made few lines of changes in kernel network subsystem where I will send the packets to my kernel module rather than to ip-stack. I have rebuilt the kernel and successfully booted with it.

Now if I try to build the same codebase on the modified kernel it takes more than 1hour 30min to complete it. Kernel version is 2.6.32.58

Can anyone help me in debugging why it takes so much time for just a single line modification in kernel ? I know it could b becos of my modification but wanna know debugging the performance issues.

Comment: You mean compilation on a machine, which uses your modified kernel, is slow? If so, your modifications probably slow things down (the networking maybe).

Comment: Yeah but the change I have done is a single line which sends the packet to my kernel module instead of sending into ip stack ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified kernel may be using too much CPU  (e.g. due to a [near] infinite loop) causing user level processes to slow down. You can find this out by putting printk messages in the modified kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The time compiled relies on your modified files and make tools.

You can make the module you will modify independently or make -jN the kernel with multithread

Comment: But I am not just compiling the kernel module but compiling the whole codebase on booting in modified kernel after doing make clean.

Comment: you might run make -j4 to use 4-threads making your codebase.